# Same name for a printer for multiple users in Terminal service or Citrix ?

Tags: terminal, printer, citrix

I have a problem in a Citrix environment, which could be the same in a TS environment.

We have 5 different citrix users on the same virtual machine (2012 Server).

A software, used by the 5 users, needs that all users use the same printer.

But in TS or Citrix, each user has a printername like "Ricoh MP 3860 from... in session 2,..."

So, the software cant work if the printer doesnt always have the same name.

Is it a way to workaround or fix that ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have print queue passing through to the session from the local client.

Have the printer mapping applied in the session on log on. You can do this by using a login script for the server or use Group Policy Preferences to map the printer on log on.